# Can anyone access to the camera by html5 in the mobile safari (ios5)?

Tags: html, safari, camera

As we can see opera software make the api to help developer to access to the camera from the web page.

Can we do it on mobile safari in ios5 ?

Besides,some guys said that they can do it on a android device.Is it really?

If you know that,please post the link following your answers.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access to the hardware by using a library like phonegap. This can be done only if phonegap and your html page are embedded in an app.
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.1.0/phonegap_camera_camera.md.html#Camera

A website, or any javascript code loaded from a real website won't be allowed to use a phone camera for security purposes.

Comment: Thank you very much and I know phonegap.Do all the devices ban this API at present?