# Access to mobile camera using HTML5 app

Tags: android, ios, html, cordova, stream

I am developing HTML5 app that will be targeted for mobile platforms (mostly iOS, Android). Case is that user will open such page and use his mobile camera to take photo and then process it.
I found that iOS browser isn't capable for HTML5 Stream API (http://caniuse.com/#feat=stream, http://mobilehtml5.org/).

I thought, that maybe I can use cordova (phonegap) plugin to access device capabilities, but I don't know so far if it solves my problem.

Can I use cordova, deploy web app and access it using mobile to get stream from camera or cordova can do it only if packaged into native app and deployed to device?

I found this ([Can anyone access to the camera by html5 in the mobile safari (ios5)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7752183/can-anyone-access-to-the-camera-by-html5-in-the-mobile-safari-ios5)) answer, but it is quite old. Is it still actual? Are there any other approaches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the iOS mobile safari can native use the image picker using an basic upload JavaScript function

Take a look on http://fineuploader.com/demos.html

I think that can help you with your task

Hope this help[image]

Comment: It can be used as workaround as I am looking for experience, where you can directly take photo or do some image processing on live camera stream.

Comment: With this you can open the camera and take the photo, then process the image on the webpage, but with the live camera processing I think is not possible through safari